# How to create a table with foreign key constraint in Liquibase?

Tags: liquibase

I am using yaml, but I guess it is almost the same as xml or json. I found that you can use addForeignKeyConstraint, but I want to add the constraint at table creation, not altering an existing table. How should I do that? Can I do something like this?

```
  - changeSet:
      id: create_questions
      author: Author
      changes:
        - createTable:
            tableName: questions
            columns:
              - column:
                  name: id
                  type: int
                  autoIncrement: true
                  constraints:
                    primaryKey: true
                    nullable: false
              - column:
                  name: user_id
                  type: int
                  constraints:
                    foreignKey:
                      referencedColumnNames: id
                      referencedTableName: users
                    nullable: false
              - column:
                  name: question
                  type: varchar(255)
                  constraints:
                    nullable: false
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I never used the YAML format, but in an XML changelog you can do this:

```
<column name="user_id" type="int">
   <constraints nullable="false" 
                foreignKeyName="fk_questions_author" 
                references="users(id)"/>
</column>
```

The equivalent YAML should be something like this:

```
- column:
    name: user_id
    type: int
    constraints:
        nullable: false
        foreignKeyName: fk_questions_author
        references: users(id)
```

Comment: but where do you define what fk_questions_author is? Do you have to write a changeSet to define it?

Comment: @godzsa: the foreign key is defined through the `references="users(id)"` part. It means it references the `id` column of the `users` table. It is pretty much the syntax you'd use in SQL: `... foreign key user_id references users(id)`